# SQL Azure export Database to own server

Tags: azure-sql-database

I'd like to export a DB from SQL Azure to a MDF-file so i can mount it on an own instance of SQL-server, but when i hit "export" in the Windows Azure managament tools, it want's me to export the database to the Azure Blob storage, and i just want to download it. How do i achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Windows Azure Management Tools does not support SQL Azure. To manage SQL Azure, you can use SQL Azure portal or standard SQL Server tools. For example, to export a database from SQL Azure,  You can use the standard SQL Server Management Studio (refer to http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlazure/archive/2010/05/19/10014014.aspx for more details). If you prefer a command line tool, you can use BCP (refer to http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlazure/archive/2010/05/21/10014019.aspx for more information).

Comment: Thing is i can't use SQL Server Management Studio to connect to SQL Azure. I try to log in through the first dialog that appears on start, and get this error http://piclair.com/data/ns8jo.jpg
Kind of weird because if i cancel the first dialog, and press "New query" and login, then i can query the DB but not open up the Object Explorer...

Comment: Which version of SQL Server Managagement Studio are you using? You need at least SQL Server 2008 R2. It is recommended to use SQL Server 2012. The express version can be downloaded for free on http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29062. Also make sure you've configured firewall rule on SQL Azure portal to allow connection from your local machine.

Comment: Thank you! Solved it by using SQL Server Management Studio 2012 :)